# Multiple pdfs from one file

Tags: workflow

Many of my classes this semester are asking for submission of homeworks through an online system that requires a PDF for each individual question.

Right now I'm using `\clearpage` after every problem so that each problem gets it's own page(s). This means that once I'm done I have to go through the PDF and break it into multiple smaller PDFs, one for each problem.

Wondering if anyone has any solutions that might be better than this. I don't think LaTeX can generate multiple PDFs from a single file, but if that was possible, it would be great for this.

Comment: no you can only get one pdf, so either do as you do make one pdf then spit using an external tool, or parameterise your tex docuemnt to make one page at a time and then run latex multiple times. making a different page each time

Comment: eg pdfseparate tool can split a pdf into separate pdf pages so it is just a mtter of running one extra command at the end

Comment: You could write to a temporary file at which pages a new question start from within the LaTeX run (if they don't all take only a single page) and use that temporary file to split the pdf at the correct pages with some tool (e.g., `pdfseparate` as suggested by @DavidCarlisle).